# Array StringLog unit testing smallest method

Tags: java

I'm a new programmer and I am trying to pass this code through a unit test using the smallest method.

```
// returns the first string in a lexicographic ordering of the log
public String smallest(){
    String smallest = log[0];

        for(int i= 0;i <= lastIndex; i++){

            if(log[i].compareTo(smallest)< 0){ //compare to smallest
                                               //known not log[i+1]

                smallest = log[i];

            } else {

                lastIndex++;
        }
        return smallest;
```

Here are my unit tests:

```
public class Test_smallest {

 ArrayStringLog strLog;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {      
    strLog = new ArrayStringLog("My StringLog",5);
}
/*
LinkedStringLog strLog;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {      
    strLog = new LinkedStringLog("My StringLog");
}
*/
@Test
public void test_1Element() {
    strLog.insert("string 1");
    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}

@Test
public void test_3Elements_smallest_at_beginning() {
    strLog.insert("string 1"); strLog.insert("string 2");
    strLog.insert("string 3"); 

    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}

@Test
public void test_3Elements_smallest_in_middle() {
    strLog.insert("string 2"); strLog.insert("string 1");
    strLog.insert("string 3"); 

    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}

@Test
public void test_3Elements_smallest_at_end() {
    strLog.insert("string 3"); strLog.insert("string 2");
    strLog.insert("string 1"); 

    assertEquals(strLog.smallest(), "string 1");
}   

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}
```

My problem is this, it passes the 1 element, and elements at beginning tests, but fails the other two and I cannot figure out why. It should be stepping through the array comparing the current index the loop is on with the one next to it.

It throws the error expected:string 2, but was string 1, and the other for expected:string 3 but was string 1. I'm trying to find the smallest string in the array no matter the location. I don't understand why its expected to see string 2 or 3, when the assertEquals is looking for string 1.

Comment: where is `lastIndex` defined - surely `log.size()` would be better

Comment: Sometimes is simply better to debug your program (and quicker)

Comment: at the top, sorry i didnt paste it in.        protected int lastIndex = -1;

Comment: any loop to `-1 -1` will not work, you need to sets its value in `smallest` based upon the size of your `log`

Comment: Im really lost on this, in my test I initialize the array with 5 "slots". I thought originally instead of doing for(i = 0; i < lastIndex - 1; i++) doing (i = 0; i < log.length; i++) but that fails all the tests.

Comment: I am confused - what is `strLog.insert` doing?  What is `log` defined as?

Comment: I have never heard of `ArrayStringLog` is it this http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall13/CSCI-GA.1133-001/programs/StringLogs/ArrayStringLog.txt ?  If so use `log.size()` in your `for loop`

Comment: this is my thought. It finds string 1 in the first element, and when its in the beginning, but not when its in any other part of the list. How do I get it to search the entire array? log.length in the for loop doesnt work either.

Comment: Can you include the unit testing library you are using? Show the import statement. Is it `JUnit` or `TestNG`? The order of 'actual' and 'expected' arguments in the assert methods is different for both of these libraries, which is confusing :)

Comment: I added an else statement to increase lastindex by 1, and now it only fails the last test. It is Junit

Comment: JUnit's assert method is `assertEquals(expected, actual)`, so you should put what you expect as the first parameter, and what your method returns as the second parameter. This will make the error easier to understand. http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Comment: Yea I dont really understand all that yet, Ive been working on this for about 12 hours, counting its LinkedList counterpart, I gotta take a break. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I figured it out, I was not comparing the string to the known smallest in the list. instead of log[i+1] it should be smallest in the .compareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop in the method `smallest()`, not sure why you need to add else condition `lastIndex++`. This variable shouldn't be change. Can you remove the condition and try again? Here's a sample of code:

```
public String smallest(){
    String smallest = log[0];
    for(int i= 0;i <= lastIndex; i++){
            if(log[i].compareTo(smallest)< 0){ //compare to smallest
                                               //known not log[i+1]
                smallest = log[i];
    }
    return smallest;
}
```